# Linq filtering does not get expected results on collection

Tags: c#

I have following criteria class:

```
public class WarehouseCriteria
{
    public WarehouseTypeEnum? WarehouseTypeEnum{ get; set; }
    public string UserLogin { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public WarehouseCriteria()
    {
        WarehouseTypeEnum = null;
        UserLogin = string.Empty;
        UserName = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I use that `class` to construct filtering over my `collection`. If `WarehouseTypeEnum` is not null then that property value has to be set otherwise excluded from filter. Same approach for rest two properties.

At the end i have this:

```
_data = new ObservableCollection<Warehouse>(_data .Where(w => criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum == null || w.TypeName.Equals(EnumTools.ConvertToString(criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum))
&& criteria.UserLogin == string.Empty || w.UserLogin.Equals(criteria.UserLogin)
&& criteria.UserName == string.Empty || w.UserName.Equals(criteria.UserName)));
```

Nevertheless something is wrong as during tests i got results as not expected, does anyone sees what could be wrong here?

Comment: What is `EnumTools` and why are you using it? You don't need it: `w.TypeName == criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum?.ToString()`

Comment: @AluanHaddad EnumTools it converts enum value to string. There is no issue with values as i debug it. I assume something is wrong with "parts" of Where - something out of 3 conditions have to be taken wrongly

Comment: Seems that your condition are not grouped together `_data = new ObservableCollection<Warehouse>(_data .Where(w => (criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum == null || w.TypeName.Equals(EnumTools.ConvertToString(criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum)))
&& (criteria.UserLogin == string.Empty || w.UserLogin.Equals(criteria.UserLogin))
&& (criteria.UserName == string.Empty || w.UserName.Equals(criteria.UserName))));`

Comment: @user1672994 they have to be? I thought && concatinating criteria and deciding based on values whether include something or not

Comment: Be that as it may, what's wrong with the built in `ToString` provided by .NET? Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Arie - check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/operator-precedence)

Comment: @Arie without the parenthesis the `&&` and `||` will be processed from left to right and as soon as you have `false` before a `&&` or `true` before a `||` it will stop evaluating the rest.

Comment: @user1672994 i think your solution works

Comment: @Arie - juharr - explained the behaviour of operators and their evaluation order.

Comment: hmm is it better to use separated .Where's maybe code to be clear or (as from answer below)?

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your requirements correctly, you can use the following.

```
_data = _data
    .Where(w => criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum == null || w.WarehouseTypeEnum == criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum)
    .Where(w => criteria.UserLogin == string.Empty || w.UserLogin.Equals(criteria.UserLogin))
    .Where(w => criteria.UserName == string.Empty || w.UserName.Equals(criteria.UserName))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not take into account operator precedence. `&&` binds stronger than `||`. On an abstract level you are doing the following

```
A || B && C || D && E || F
```

which is evaluated as follows

```
A || (B && C) || (D && E) || F
```

but you want

```
(A || B) && (C || D) && (E || F)
```

So in your code you are doing the following

```
_data = new ObservableCollection<Warehouse>(_data .Where(w => 
    c.WarehouseTypeEnum == null || //Condition 1 OR
    (w.TypeName.Equals(EnumTools.ConvertToString(criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum)) && criteria.UserLogin == string.Empty) || //(C2 && C3) OR
    (w.UserLogin.Equals(criteria.UserLogin) && criteria.UserName == string.Empty) ||  (C4 && C5) OR
    w.UserName.Equals(criteria.UserName)  //C6
    )
);
```

which is obviously nonsense. So for instance, whenever `c.WareHouseTypeEnum` is `null` the element will be included in the result, regardless what the other values are.

Add parenthesis on the correct places like below

```
_data = new ObservableCollection<Warehouse>(_data .Where(w => 
    (criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum == null || w.TypeName.Equals(EnumTools.ConvertToString(criteria.WarehouseTypeEnum))) &&  // (C1 or C2) AND 
    (criteria.UserLogin == string.Empty || w.UserLogin.Equals(criteria.UserLogin)) && // (C3 or C4) AND
    (criteria.UserName == string.Empty || w.UserName.Equals(criteria.UserName)) //(C5 and C6)
    )
);
```